# MUI: You have provided an out-of-range value `18:00` for the select component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use react with Mui;

```
<Select
  disabled={disable}
  renderValue={(value) => renderValue(value as number)}
  size="small"
  value={object.time}
  onChange={({ target }) => onChange(target.value as string)}
>
  {hours.map((hour) => (
    <MenuItem key={hour.id} value={hour.val1}>
      <ListItemText title={hour.time} primary={hour.time} />
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</Select>
```

I tried using many solutions like add `defaultValue=""` or stringify the value but none helped

Comment: i guess the warning occurs if `object.time` is `undefined`.
try `value={object.time || ""}`